# QT showstatus tip is shown only after mouse leave the window and return

Tags: c++, qt

I have a mainwindow and I'm trying to show in statusarea message when user is trying open file that don't exist.

```
void MainWindow::onOpenClicked(){
    if(QFile(ui->lineEditCapture->text()).exists()){
        // allow opening for analyze
    }else{
        setStatusTip("Can't open file, check if the file name is correct");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the statustip is shown only after the mouse pointer leaves the window and return.

Also when I do

```
setStatusTip("Can't open file, check if the file name is correct");
```

in constructor then the statustip is shown right away.

What could be wrong?

EDIT:
It looks like if I do setStatusTip in slot then it's not working as it should, however if the setStatusTip is in normal method then it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`showMessage`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html#showMessage) function instead of the `setStatusTip`. This way you can control how long the message will be displayed:

> If timeout is 0 (default), the message remains displayed until the
>   clearMessage() slot is called or until the showMessage() slot is
>   called again to change the message.

```
if (statusBar())
    statusBar()->showMessage("Can't open file, check if the file name is correct");
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it works as expected, I think i'll be using this.
But why setting it with setstatutip don't work in slots? is it some kind of bug?

Comment: `setStatusTip` is used when you want to display temporarily something on the status bar, eg when you are hovering over a button...

Comment: I understand now what I did wrong, I didn't actually show the message but only set the message. That's why it is shown only if the mouse enter the mainwindow. Thanks, it was so simple and stupid